# C++ Getting Date Modified of Recycle Bin

Tags: c++, recycle-bin, datemodified

I have some simple code attempting to get the last modified date of the users recycle bin. This code seems to work on other files however it does not work on the recycle bin. I've done some looking into and it seems the recycle bin is a special file as in it's not a regular file. This would explain why I'm getting Unix epoch as the result. Here is my code:

```
struct tm* tmDateModified;
struct stat attribute;
stat("C:\\$Recycle.Bin\\Recycle Bin", &attribute);
tmDateModified = gmtime(&(attribute.st_mtime));
std::string date = asctime(tmDateModified);
String^ date2 = marshal_as<String^>(date);
MessageBox::Show(date2);
```

When I execute this code, the MessageBox displays **Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 1970** as the result, again that's Unix epoch. I know this is possible as I've seen it done before in other applications, however, I don't have access to their source so I can't exactly figure out how they did it. If anyone knows why Unix epoch is being displayed rather than the actual date modified and how to fix it, I'll take any help.

Comment: That "ridiculous date" would be [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), or in other words zero. If you step through this code in your debugger, is there any point at which the timestamp becomes zero or NULL?

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://prntscr.com/ilpdnr

Comment: There is no file actually named "Recycle Bin" in that directory. Explorer shows you that name, but it's actually a SID. CD to it in a command prompt and 'dir /ahs'.

Comment: Ok I was able to find it, I believe this is what you meant, http://prntscr.com/ilpk7h but would this work on others computers, or would this be different? If so how would I go by getting theirs? @RetiredNinja